# Auto add checkbox values and keep their name for storing in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I have checkboxes retrieved from my database with respective item_name and value which happen to be displayed correctly, but the values are being added/subtracted automatically when selected/checked. However, i want to save the selected check box item_names and also the total sum of the values from the checkboxes. I can't accomplish this because the value option holds numeric data which should have been the checkbox item_name; here is so far what i have.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkTotal() {
        document.listForm.total.value = '';
        var sum = 0;
        for (i=0;i<document.listForm.sel_car.length;i++) {
          if (document.listForm.sel_car[i].checked) {
            sum = sum + parseInt(document.listForm.sel_ca[i].value);
          }
        }
        document.listForm.total.value = sum;
    }
</script>
```

HTML/PHP Snippet

```
    <h4>Available Cars | Click on desired car(Multiple Selections enabled) | Total Price: <input type="text" size="2" name="total" value="0"/></h4>
        <div class="form-group">

        <?php

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY car_id DESC');
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row);
            ?>  
        <div class="col-md-3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
            <img src="user_images/<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail img-check"><input type="checkbox" name="sel_car[]" id="item4" value="<?php echo $row['car_price']; ?>" class="hidden" autocomplete="off"  onchange="checkTotal()"/>
            <h5><?php echo $row['se_car_model']; ?> | UGX <?php echo $row['car_price']; ?>/=</h5>
            </label></div>

<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also retrieve id along with Item name and value and assign the id to the checkbox.

**Add the hidden field in the form**

```
<input type="hidden" name="itemsArr" id="itemsArr" value="">
```

**checkbox**

```
<input onclick="checkTotal(this)" type="checkbox" id="itemId" name="ItemName" value="ItemPrice">
```

**Div showing total amount**

```
<div id="totalDiv"></div>
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = [];
var total = 0;
function checkTotal($this)
    {
        var varId= $this.id;
        if ($($this).is(":checked")) {
            arr.push(varId);
        }
        else
        {
            arr.splice( $.inArray(varId,arr) ,1 );
        }
        $("#itemsArr").val(arr);

        // get the price of the item from the controller by passing id to controller

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: BASE_URL+"controllerName/methodName",
            data: {'id':varId},
            success: function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                total += data.price;

                $("#totalDiv").html(total);
            }
        });
    }
```

On sumbitting the form you will be getting the hidden value and then store it in the database

When you want to retrieve the value from the database you can get the field and convert that string into an array using explode function and do the further tasks.

Comment: can i have an illustration on this @rishi

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... I have updated my post. Please check it @McDonaldEgesaDonatius